# Get top/left coordinates of element being dragged (not pointer)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have this jQuery UI draggable element:

```
<span id="dragme">Rectangle</span>
```

When I drop this element in a droppable div, I get the top/left coordinates like so:

```
 drop: (event, ui) => {
        const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const top = event.clientY - rect.top;
        const left = event.clientX - rect.left;
 }
```

This works fine, but the problem is that the top/left coordinates that I get are the mouse pointer coordinates and I need the top/left of the element that is being dragged:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

Comment: basically you record the offset when drag start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `offset()` for get the exact position.

```
drop: (event, ui) => {
        const rect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const top = $("#dragme").offset().top;
        const left = $("#dragme").offset().left;
 }
```